# ElasticStack- Error “Saved field “timeStamp” of data view “index” is invalid for use with the “Date Histogram” aggregation. Please select a new field

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat, logstash-filter

I'm running Elastic Stack 8.3.0.
I encounter the following error in Kibana "Discover" with an index:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2ZTx.png)

The index is indexed from the following csv file:

> timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,Hostname,IdleTime,Connect
> 2023/09/17 02:23:03.892,167,otcs_user_interface-1,200,,login-browse-upload-download-search-logout 1-1,text,true,,10746,681,1,1,http://{URL},113,{HostName},0,30
> 2023/09/17 02:23:03.892,113,otcs_user_interface-1-0,302,,login-browse-upload-download-search-logout 1-1,text,true,,2420,143,1,1,http://{URL},113,{HostName},0,30
> 2023/09/17 02:23:04.008,51,otcs_user_interface-1-1,200,,login-browse-upload-download-search-logout 1-1,text,true,,8326,538,1,1,http://{URL},51,{HostName},0,0
> 2023/09/17 02:23:04.100,3,Debug Sampler,200,OK,login-browse-upload-download-search-logout 1-1,text,true,,2657,0,1,1,null,0,{HostName},0,0
> 2023/09/17 02:23:04.104,9,login-2,200,,login-browse-upload-download-search-logout 1-1,text,true,,8041,471,1,1,http://{URL},9,{HostName},0,0

I use Filebeat to collect this csv log to logstash, this is my logstash pipeline:

> input {
>
> beats {
> port => "${beats_port}"
> ssl => true
> ssl_certificate_authorities => ["${ssl_certificate_authorities}"]
> ssl_certificate => "${ssl_certificate}"
> ssl_key => "${ssl_key}"
> ssl_verify_mode => "peer"
> }
> }
>
> filter {
>
> if "login-browse-upload-download-search-logout" in [tags]{
> csv {
> columns => ["timeStamp", "elapsed", "label", "responseCode", "responseMessage", "threadName", "dataType", "success", "failureMessage", "bytes", "sentBytes", "grpThreads", "allThreads", "URL", "Latency", "Hostname", "IdleTime","Connect"]
> separator => ","
> convert => {"elapsed" => "integer"}
> }
> date {
> match => [ "timeStamp", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" ]
> target => "timeStamp"
> }
> mutate {
> gsub => ["threadName", " 1-1", ""]
> }
> mutate {
> rename => ["threadName", "TestcaseName"]
> remove_field => ["responseCode"]
> remove_field => ["responseMessage"]
> remove_field => ["dataType"]
> remove_field => ["bytes"]
> remove_field => ["sentBytes"]
> remove_field => ["grpThreads"]
> remove_field => ["allThreads"]
> remove_field => ["URL"]
> remove_field => ["Latency"]
> remove_field => ["IdleTime"]
> remove_field => ["Connect"]
> }
>
> if [label] == "login_logout-testcase" or [label] == "browse-testcase" or [label] == "export_content-testcase" or [label] == "import_content-testcase" or [label] == "search-testcase" or [label] == "login-browse-upload-download-search-logout-testcase" {
> if [success] == "true" {
> mutate {
> add_field => {"Testcase_Status" => "success" }
> }
> }
> else {
> mutate {
> add_field => {"Testcase_Status" => "failure" }
> }
> }
>
> mutate {
> rename => ["elapsed", "Testcase_ExecutionTime"]
> remove_field => ["label"]
> remove_field => ["success"]
> remove_field => ["failureMessage"]
> }
> }
> else {
> mutate {
> rename => ["label", "Transaction_Name"]
> rename => ["failureMessage", "Transaction_ErrorMessage"]
> }
>
> if [success] == "true" {
> mutate {
> add_field => {"Transaction_Status" => "success" }
> }
> }
> else {
> mutate {
> add_field => {"Transaction_Status" => "failure" }
> }
> }
>
> mutate {
> remove_field => ["elapsed"]
> remove_field => ["success"]
> }
> }
> }
> }
>
> Output {
> if "login-browse-upload-download-search-logout" in [tags]{
> elasticsearch {
> hosts => ["${elasticsearch_host}:${elasticsearch_port}"]
> index => "otcs_unit_transactions-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}-000001"
> user => "${logstash_writer_username}"
> password => "${logstash_writer_password}"
> ssl => true
> ssl_certificate_verification => true
> cacert => "${cacert}"
> ilm_enabled => true
> ilm_rollover_alias => "otcs_unit_transactions"
> ilm_pattern => "{now/d}-000001"
> ilm_policy => "otcs_unit_transactions_ilm"
> }
> }
> }

As you can see I have a Date filter plugin, not sure if there is an error there that prevents logstsash from parsing the correct date format to the timeStamp column. Has anyone encounter this error?